# Root invalid default shell

Tags: bash, ssh, sudo, root, chsh

We have a server with `ssh` enabled, and we have: `PermitRootLogin: no`, and a user that is not in `sudoers` file. Another administator set invalid Shell for `root` so I can't get `root` access anymore. When I run `su` command and enter `root` password it says: `su: failed to execute /bin/vash`. I think the `admin` wanted to set `bash` as default Shell but here is a typo.
How can I access `root` again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man su`:

```
   -s, --shell=shell
          Run the specified shell instead of the default.
```

So try:

```
su root -s /bin/sh
```

Then run `chsh` to reset the shell to a valid default

Comment: So I wasn't in sudoers file) But I've already fixed that

Answer (score 0):

Oh guys I've fixed that)))
Here is my solution:

```
cp /bin/bash ~/vash
export PATH = "$PATH:~"
alias "/bin/vash"="/home/USER/vash"
su
```

Comment: I'm struggling to see how this can possibly work - how does an alias defined in the unprivileged shell have any effect on how `su` locates `/bin/vash`? and `export PATH = "$PATH:~"` is invalid (for more than one reason) in at least bash/dash/zsh/ksh. Can you check your command history please?

Comment: @steeldriver Hello, My history matches my post. I understand your doubts because I also wonder how it works but it helped me to access root shell (there I ran chsh command and set bash as a default shell). Maybe I'll try to repeat this on a VM.